# DataWedge library - Motorola MC55 barcode scanning very slow

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, barcode, motorola

I have Motorola MC55 with DataWedge 3.2.4 installed. The issue I encounter is very slow scanning of barcodes, especially those prefixed with 'U' letter. I open the notepad and scan a barcode, text appears very slowly (even 2sec after barcode key trigger). How to tune/fix it to have more performant scanning capability?

Regards
Dominik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue with mc55. Just turn off the word-completion and auto correct in settings/personal/input/word completion.

Answer (score 0):

Does the device have a traditional barcode scanner, or is it using the camera to decode the barcode?  The traditional barcode scanner is usually faster.

Comment: Hello. Thank for response. I've figured out the problem. It is an issue with DataWedge library and the fact it transfers the barcodes to edit controls via copy char, not copy text. This causes performance lags. I decided to use another Motorola library - EMDK. Although more difficult in usage, it provides far more reliability and performant scanning.